# Question about pointwise canonically weakly pseudocompact space.

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

A point $x$ of a space $X$ is said to be a point of canonical weak pseudocompactness if the following condition is satisfied:

> For every canonical open subset $U$ of $X$ such that $x\in\overline{U}$, there exists a sequence 
>   $\{A_n:n\in\omega\}$ of subsets of $U$ such that $x\in\overline{A_n}$, for each $n\in \omega$, and for every 
>   indexed family $\xi=\{O_n:n\in\omega\}$ of open subsets of $X$ satisfying $O_n\cap A_n\neq\varnothing$
>   for all $n\in\omega$, the family $\xi$ has an accumulation point in $X$.

A space $X$ is pointwise canonically weakly pseudocompact if each point of $X$ is a 
point of canonical weak pseudocompactness.

1. How can we show that Every compact topological group is a pointwise canonically weakly pseudocompact space?
2. Is it true that every dyadic compactum is a pointwise canonically weakly pseudocompact space?

If 2 is true then 1 has also proven since Every compact topological 
group $G$ is a dyadic compactum.

---

An open subset $U$ of a space $X$ is said to be canonical open in $X$ if $U$ is the 
interior of its closure.

I added a few references that I hope will clarify the issue;

[1](http://books.google.com/books?id=hIEnzrOBbW0C&pg=PA359&lpg=PA359&dq=pointwise%20canonically%20weakly%20pseudocompact&source=bl&ots=fVNfP135tk&sig=Qy7cRLPVlXbT9YQrh1isrAKNAgc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KbtiUfmfIInssgbIzoDIAw&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=pointwise%20canonically%20weakly%20pseudocompact&f=false). A.V. Arkhangel'skii and M. Tkachenko, *Topological Groups and Related Structures*, p359.

[2](http://topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v25/tp25222.pdf). A.V. Arhangel’skii, *Moscow Spaces and Topological Groups*, p404.

[3](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/119068).A.V. Arhangel'skii, *On a theorem of W.W. Comfort and K.A. Ross*, p141.

Comment: What is meaning of the family $\xi$ has an accumulation point of $X$?

Comment: What you refer to as “canonical open set” is usually called a regular open set.

Comment: @Paul: $\xi$ is not locally finit at a point in $X$.

Comment: @tomasz: Yes, you're right. “Regular open” has been used in recent references. But in the defenition of pointwise canonically weakly pseudocompact space, The “canonically” refers to canonical open sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@TXC: This questions seems to be trivial (or I misunderstood it).  If a space $X$ is pseudocompact (a feebly compact, in Tkachenko’s terminology), then, by the definition of a pseudocompact space, the family $\xi$ cannot be locally finite. In particular, each compact space is pointwise canonically weakly pseudocompact.

Comment: Thank you for attention to this question. how we can show that the first condition ( For every canonical open subset $U$ of $X$ such that $x\in\overline{U}$, there exists a sequence $\{A_n:n∈ω\}$ of subsets of $U$ such that $x\in \overline{A_n
}$, for each $n∈ω$ ) ?

Comment: If $X$ is pseudocompact, then you can put $A_n=U$ for each $n$.

Comment: Is every Frechet-urysohn space is a pointwise canonically weakly pseudocompact space? let $U$ be a canonical open subset $X$ such that $x∈\overline{U}$, for every open nbhood $N$ of $x$ there exist a $n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$ we have $x_n∈N$. now choose $α=\sup\{n_i\}$. therfore for every open nbhood of $x$ this nbhood contains all of $x_n>x_α$ and put $A_n=\{x_α,x_{α+1},...\}$. This $A_n$ implie that $X$ is a pointwise canonically weakly pseudocompact. Am i right?

Comment: You should be right. As a professional reviewer, :-) I slightly rewrite your idea. Let $X$ be a Fréchet-Urysohn space, $U$ be a subset of $X$ and $x\in\overline U$. Then there exist a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of points of $U$, convergent to $x$. For each $n$ put $A_n=\{x_m:m\ge n\}$. Then $x\in\overline A_n$ for each $n$. Let $\xi=\{O_n\}$ be a family of open subsets of $X$ such that $A_n\cap O_n\not=\varnothing$ for each $n$.

Comment: Suppose that $x$ is not an accumulation point of the family $\xi$. Then there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $x$, intersecting only finitely many $O_n$’s. Therefore there exists a number $N_1$ such that $V\cap O_n=\varnothing$ for each $n>N_1$. Moreover, since $x$ is a limit of the sequence $x_n$, therefore there exists a number $N_2$ such that $x_n\in V$ for each $n>N_2$. Put $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}+1$. Then $O_N\cap A_N\subset O_N\cap V=\varnothing$, a contradiction.

Comment: The [third reference](http://emis.matem.unam.mx/journals/CMUC/pdf/cmuc9901/arhangel.pdf), page 141 stated that all pointwise pseudocompact spaces, are pointwise weakly pseudocompact. But I can not prove it. Can I ask you to please help me to prove?

Comment: @TXC This claim seems to be obvious too. Let $a$ be a pseudocompacteness point of
a space $X$. Let $\{U_n:n\in\omega\}$ be a family of open neighborhoods of
$a$, satisfying the condition from the definition of a pseudocompacteness point
at page 137. For each $n$ put $A_n=U_n$. Then the family $\{U_n:n\in\omega\}$
should satisfy Condition (wp) from the definition of a weakly pseudocompacteness point
at page 141. Indeed, let $\eta=\{O_n:n\in\omega\}$ be a family of open subsets
of $X$, satisfying the condition $V_n=O_n\cap A_n\not=\emptyset$ for each $n\in\omega$.

Comment: Then the
sequence $\{V_n:n\in\omega\}$ satisfies the condition from the definition of a pseudocompacteness
point at page 137. Therefore the sequence $\{V_n:n\in\omega\}$ has an accumulation
point $b$ in $X$, which is also an accumulation point of the family $\eta$.

Comment: But in the definition of weakly pseudocompacteness point, for every $n\in\omega$, $A_n \subset U$, where $a\in U$ is an open subset of $X$ and $a\in\overline{U}$. if we choose for each $n$, $A_n=U_n\cap U$. Then is it true that for every $n\in\omega$, $a\in \overline{A_n}$?

Comment: But in the definition of weakly pseudocompacteness point, for every $n∈ω$ , $A_n ⊂U$ , where $U$ is an open subset of $X$ and $a∈\overline{U}$.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that $U$. The answer to your question is positive. Indeed, let $V$ be any neighborhood of $a$. Let $n$ be arbitrary. Then $V\cap U_n$ is a neighborhood of $a$ too. Since $a\in\overline{U}$, $(V\cap A_n)=V\cap (U_n\cap U)=(V\cap U_n)\cap U\not=\emptyset$. Thus $a\in\overline {A_n}$.